# Wordpress - Contact Form 7 number field step and required attribute

Tags: html, wordpress

I have problems adding required and step attributes in Custom Form 7 number fields. I have tried using two different methods in the same form and have two different problems

I am trying to add a required number field and a step size of 0.05.

1) `[number* number-491 id:abc min:0 max:100000 step:0.05 placeholder “CMP*”]` – This honors the step size attribute but NOT the step:0.05

2) `<input type=”number” name=“CMP” placeholder=“CMP*” min=0 max=100000 step=“0.05” required/>` – This honors the step size attribute but not the required attribute.

I am OK with using either or an alternate method, all I want is a number field that will be a required field and a step size of 0.05.

Comment: Problem is that, the number type in contact form 7 does not accept float (decimal) as value for step attribute. Int (integer) is hardcoded in the tag generation code. Thats why when you set the step value as "0.05" it does not print the step attribute in the code of number field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this via customization. Use following code in your theme's or child-theme's functions.php file.

```
    function wpcf7_number_floating_step_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    if ( empty( $tag->name ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    if( $tag->type == 'numberstepfloat*' ){
        $tag->type = 'number*';
        $tag->basetype = 'number';
    }

    $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error( $tag->name );

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );

    $class .= ' wpcf7-validates-as-number-decimal';

    if ( $validation_error ) {
        $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';
    }

    $atts = array();
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'signed_int', true );
    $atts['min'] = $tag->get_option( 'min', 'signed_int', true );
    $atts['max'] = $tag->get_option( 'max', 'signed_int', true );
    $atts['step'] = $tag->get_option( 'step', '', true );

    if ( $tag->has_option( 'readonly' ) ) {
        $atts['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    }

    if ( $tag->is_required() ) {
        $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';
    }

    $atts['aria-invalid'] = $validation_error ? 'true' : 'false';

    $value = (string) reset( $tag->values );

    if ( $tag->has_option( 'placeholder' ) || $tag->has_option( 'watermark' ) ) {
        $atts['placeholder'] = $value;
        $value = '';
    }

    $value = $tag->get_default_option( $value );

    $value = wpcf7_get_hangover( $tag->name, $value );

    $atts['value'] = $value;

    if ( wpcf7_support_html5() ) {
        $atts['type'] = $tag->basetype;
    } else {
        $atts['type'] = 'text';
    }

    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;

    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input %2$s />%3$s</span>',
        sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error );

    return $html;
}

function custom_add_form_tag_floatingnumber() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( array( 'numberstepfloat', 'numberstepfloat*' ), 'wpcf7_number_floating_step_form_tag_handler', array( 'name-attr' => true ) );
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_form_tag_floatingnumber' );

function custom_numberstepfloat_validation($result, $tag){
    $customnumfield = $tag->name;
    if($_POST[$customnumfield]=='' || $_POST[$customnumfield]==null){
        $result->invalidate( $tag, "This field is required." );
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_numberstepfloat*', 'custom_numberstepfloat_validation', 20, 2 );
```

What above code does is, ads a custom form tag "numberstepfloat" which actually outputs input type number but includes the step attribute. Another function in the code ads validation for the custom tag. Validation only checks if the value is present. If not invalidates the field.

Similar to native tags in Contact Form  7, the custom tag is to be used as follows.

```
[numberstepfloat* number-491 min:0 max:100000 step:0.05 id:abc placeholder "CMP*"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @zipkundan. I added your code to the my theme's functions.php file. It works perfectly for `numberstepfloat*` (required), I get the steps in increments of 0.05 or anything I specify, however when I used `numberstepfloat` my fields got resized. As such, for non-required fields I reverted to
 
`<input type="number" name="CMP" placeholder="CMP*" min=0 max=100000 step="0.05" >`

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can adjust field's size via css. That should be manageable. Contact Form 7 css rules are tied wit filed type. Like, input[type="number"] etc. But you can apply custom class to your "numberstepfloat" type fields and add custom css rules for them. By the way, since the answer solved your primary problem, can you mark it as accepted?

Comment: I tried it in the css, '#abc{
step: 0.05
}'

however I get an error "Unknown property 'step'. Your code helped resolve my issue. I was not aware that I need to mark it as accepted, did it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: 'step" is not correct css property. If you can let me know how you want to stylise the field I will try to help with proper css.

Comment: Thank you very much @zipkundan for following up on this. I was able to resolve both my issues using your code and the html code in my question. I am a beginner and will be needing more help. If you are kindly able to help me with other issues I will appreciate it. As of now, lets say I have two fields and some radio buttons, I want to be able to prevent the submit button from being pressed if the value in one of the field is greater than the other field.

Comment: I have two number fields that I would like to compare before the submit button can be pressed.

`[radio BS use_label_element default:1 “B” “S”]`

`[number* T1 min:0 max:100000 id:T1 placeholder “Target 1*”]`

`<input type=”number” name=”T2″ min=0 max=100000 id:T2 placeholder=”Target 2″>`

I want to be able to compare the values of T1 and T2 based on the value of the radio buttons “B” and “S”. Say if radio button “B” is selected the form should not submit if the value of T2 is smaller than T1 etc. Is there a way to achieve this using Contact Form 7 or some other way?

Comment: I think that should be possible through jQuery. You will need 2 function. One function like "document.ready" via which you can disable the submit button in your form. And Second function like, ".change" which will watch the change event of your form input. In this function you can write your comparison logic and when your logic results favourably, you can enable the submit button in the form. Hope this gives you some direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will google some more based on your suggestion and see if I am able to achieve the required functionality. In case I succeed will add the code here.